# Word for person who was ignored by everyone while alive, but whose importance was realized after he died

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

Is there a single word for a person who was ignored by everyone when he was alive, but later people realized his importance after he died? It can also be related to his work, teaching or something like that.

Comment: Do you mean an artist? ;-)

Comment: It can be artist . But what do we call them in general?

Comment: how about "*ahead of their time*"

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:british-english]?

Comment: The undertaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [unrecognized genius](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22midnight%20belongs%20to%20the%20new%20day%22&oq=%22midnight%20belongs%20to%20the%20new%20day%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l2.9380&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=serp&pq=posthumously%20appreciated&cp=15&gs_id=26&xhr=t&q=unrecognized%20genius&es_nrs=true&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=unrecognized%20ge&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41018144,d.d2k&fp=b626e77c3d9f15de&biw=1149&bih=864) may be [posthumously appreciated](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22midnight%20belongs%20to%20the%20new%20day%22&oq=%22midnight%20belongs%20to%20the%20new%20day%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l2.9380&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=Posthumously%20Appreciated&oq=Posthumously%20Appreciated&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i8i30.1428387.1431150.0.1431953.18.10.0.0.0.4.105.560.9j1.10.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.7bknng8w0mw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41018144,d.d2k&fp=b626e77c3d9f15de&biw=1149&bih=864).

Comment: I think you're on the right track here. I'm not sure there's a single word that explicitly means what the O.P. is after, but I seem to recall hearing phrases like _unappreciated during his time_ or _unrecognized by his contemporaries_ before.

Comment: neglected genius

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic phrases like *[unsung hero](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unsung_hero)* and *prophet before his time* in part have such senses.  The latter term implies that the person's importance eventually is recognized.  However, as in FumbleFingers' *unrecognized genius* answer, posthumous appreciation is not a given for an *unsung hero*.  For most of these terms, a person's importance may be recognized before or after death, or may never be recognized.

Also consider  *[sleeper](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sleeper#Noun)*, in its sense “Something that achieves unexpected success after an interval of time”, and  *[dark horse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dark_horse#Noun)* in its sense “An unexpected success”.

Comment: +1 for *unsung hero* - but it doesn't quite fit OP's requirement. For example, it's probably fair to say Vincent Van Gogh wasn't much recognised during his lifetime, but you could hardly call him an "unsung hero" today. Usually we only use this term when trying to get others to appreciate someone that *we* already recognise, but most people don't (yet! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would call him a *visionary unrecognized in his own time*.

Answer (score 0):

You could call that person a pioneer. They are often not recognised for their accomplishments until later (or at least not until after they go into uncharted territory where no other person has tread). I should note that it can also be used to describe someone who is still alive - its definition doesn't exclusively describe a deceased person.

However, it depends on the context in which you use the word.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say he was "a man ahead of his time" (or "a woman ahead of her time").

Answer (score -1):

It would be appropriate to call him/her an unsung hero

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, we ask that you take the time to explain why you think your answer is good, and especially encourage the practice of quoting dictionaries when responding to word requests.